# How do I find the 1st non-NA value in a row?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Suppose I have the following:

```
df <- data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2019-02-02'), as.Date('2019-02-04'), as.Date('2019-02-05'), as.Date('2020-03-04')), v1=c(1,2,NA,NA), v2=c(NA,3,4,NA), v3=c(NA,NA,3,5), v4=c(2, 4, 6, NA))
> read.zoo(df)
           v1 v2 v3 v4
2019-02-02  1 NA NA  2
2019-02-04  2  3 NA  4
2019-02-05 NA  4  3  6
2020-03-04 NA NA  5 NA
```

**I would like to find the first non-NA value on each row that occur after a column that had a value.**

So for example, for '2019-02-02':

- there is a value in `v1` of 1, v2 has NA so we skip, `v3` has NA so we skip but `v4` is NOT NA so I would like to return its value, 2 for row 1, col 1.
- Looking at the next column, `v2`, in the same row it is NA so we skip it since it is not a number
- `v3` is also NA so we skip it.
- `v4` is NOT NA but there are no columns following it so we return NA.

Therefore our 1st row will be:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
2  NA NA NA
```

Going through all the rows in this example I am expecting the output to be:

```
             c1 c2 c3 c4
1 2019-02-02  2 NA NA NA
2 2019-02-04  3  4 NA NA
3 2019-02-05 NA  3  6 NA
4 2020-03-04 NA NA NA NA
```

It looks like all I need to do is shift the column values in each row to the left but I can't seem to figure out how to do it...

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution using zoo

Comment: It looks like `v1` doesn't matter---is this correct?

Comment: It does matter, because if `v1` is NA then `c1` will be NA in that row (since we skip NAs). If `v1` is NOT NA then `c1` might have a value from some column to the right of `v1` (if some column to the right of `v1` is non-NA)

Comment: Ah, the "shift the column values in each row to the left" description made sense.

Comment: :-) It a bit hard to explain this question but this has me stomped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution applying a custom function:

```
res = t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
     val = which(!is.na(x))
     x[val[-length(val)]] = x[val[-1]]
     x[val[length(val)]] = NA
     return(x)
     }
  ))

cbind(df[1], res)
#           dt v1 v2 v3 v4
# 1 2019-02-02  2 NA NA NA
# 2 2019-02-04  3  4 NA NA
# 3 2019-02-05 NA  3  6 NA
# 4 2020-03-04 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: This is pretty clever. Need to think about it :-) Would definitely be helpful for anyone in the future looking at this if you have a brief explanation of why this works...

Comment: Ah, I see how you did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with `base` R. But in `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
gather(key, value, -dt) %>% 
arrange(dt, key) %>% 
mutate(key2 = as.numeric(substr(key, 2, 2))) %>% 
filter(!is.na(value)) %>% group_by(dt) %>% 
mutate(ind = lag(key2, default = NA), index = paste0("c", ind)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
filter(!is.na(ind)) %>% 
select(dt, index, value) %>% 
spread(index, value)
```